# Automating Reverse Image Search and Renaming Images

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Want to create an a python program that reverse image searches and image and finds the name of the movie, drama, animation etc and renames the image in a particular format (Counter_PictureName_Date,fileextension).

Wrote a little bit of code but it does not seem to be working

```
from GoogleSearch import Search

#file_path example
output = Search(file_path=os.path.join('E:\\', 'Image Rename', 'Untitled.png'))

print(output)
```

Problem occurring is that output is:
`{'similar': 'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=', 'output': ''}`

Kindly, In dire need of guidance, what am I doing wrong? what approach should I follow.
Thank You.